# How to scale down and translate right to left using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, animation

I have a background of backend developer (nodejs) and I'm starting to develop web application. So I'm really new to HTML5, CSS. You can check the small web application [here](http://get.movistapp.com).

Now I want to add some animations to the web application. The first animation is a scale down of the current state and a translation right to left of the new state and I don't know where to start. I'm using `ui-router`, `Restangular` and `ngAnimate` as AngularJS dependencies, `LESS` for CSS pre-processing.

Any idea how can I achieve these animations (scale down the current state and translate right to left the next state) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough, but from what I understand, here is an example to help you. You can add a class to your element in javascript and use CSS translate and transform :

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button'),
  box = document.getElementById('box')

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  box.classList.add("move");
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: orange;
  transition: all 1s;
}
button {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.move {
  transform: translate(-200px, 0);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button id="button">click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. English isn't my language and I'm still learning so it's difficult for me to really express my thoughts clearly. Now that you show me how to scale down, how can I push (right to left) a second box that will take the place of the first box ? So transitions are second box hide on the right side of the first box, the first box scale down and fade out, the second box pushed to the left and fade in.